Probability distribution function for sum of two independent random variables
In measure theory, given two independent random variables $X_1,X_2:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)\to(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B})$, I want to proof that the distribution function of $X_1+X_2$ is
$$
\mu_{X_1+X_2}(B)=\int \mu_{X_1}(B-y)\mu_{X_2}(dy)\qquad \mbox{ for }B\in\mathscr{B}
$$
However, I'm not familiar with some notations and want to prove only by definitions $\mu_X(B)\triangleq \mu(X^{-1}(B))$.
I tried to consider the measure of the set:
$$
\mu((X_1+X_2)^{-1}(B))
$$
but I don't know how to step forward.
*I know the following possible solution
$$
\mu_{X_1+X_2}(B)=\int P(X_1\in B-y,X_2\in dy)=\int \mu_{X_1}(X_1\in B-y)\mu_{X_2}(dy)
$$
but I'm really confused with the notation "$X_2\in dy$"

Denote the distributions of $X_{1},X_{2}$, and the random vector $(X_{1},X_{2})$
by $\mu_{1},\mu_{2}$ and $\nu$ respectively. Since $X_{1},X_{2}$
are independent, it is well-known that $\nu=\mu_{1}\times\mu_{2}$.
(The equality holds for sets of the form $(-\infty,a]\times(-\infty,b]$.
Note that $\{(-\infty,a]\times(-\infty,b]\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$
is a $\pi$-class on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and is also a generator of
$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$. The result follows by invoking Dynkin's
$\pi$-$\lambda$ Theorem.)
Let $\mathcal{B}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. We have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \mu_{X_{1}+X_{2}}(B)\\
 & = & \int1_{B}(X_{1}+X_{2})\,dP\\
 & = & \int1_{B}(x+y)\,d\nu(x,y).
\end{eqnarray*}
Here, the first equality is due to the fact that $1_{\left(X_{1}+X_{2}\right)^{-1}(B)}(\omega)=1_{B}(X_{1}(\omega)+X_{2}(\omega))$
for any $\omega\in\Omega$, which can be verified directly.
The second equality is due to Doob: If $\phi:\mathcal{\mathbb{R}}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
is a bounded Borel function, then $\int\phi(x,y)\,d\nu(x,y)=\int\phi(X,Y)\,dP$.
(For our case, $\phi(x,y)=1_{B}(x+y)$.) This fact can be proven by
firstly considering the case that $\phi=1_{C}$ for some Borel set
$C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}$, then by linearity, the case that $\phi$
is a simple function, then by Monotone Convergence Theorem, the case
that $\phi$ is non-negative Borel...
Now, we further have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int1_{B}(x+y)\,d\nu(x,y)\\
 & = & \int\int1_{B}(x+y)\,d\mu_{1}(x)d\mu_{2}(y)\\
 & = & \int\mu_{1}(B-y)\,d\mu_{2}(y).
\end{eqnarray*}
The last equality is justified as follows: Fix $y\in\mathbb{R}$.
Note that $1_{B}(x+y)$ assumes values $0,1$ only and $1_{B}(x+y)=1$
iff $x\in B-y$. Hence, $\int1_{B}(x+y)d\mu_{1}(x)=\int1_{B-y}(x)d\mu_{1}(x)=\mu_{1}(B-y)$.
